# How to validate string with RegExp()

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a problem that I want to validate input field using `RegExp()`. Allows entering digits, characters and special character "_" to get the last string: **regex3_example**. When pressing the space key, "_" will be displayed. Hope everybody help please. Thank you!

```
document.querySelector('#input').addEventListener('input', function () {
    var text = this.value;

    if (re.test(text)) {
        console.log("Valid");
    } else {
        console.log("Invalid");
    }
    $(document).keypress(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 32) {
            var re = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z_]");
            var insert_string = text+'_';
            let insert_text = insert_string.trim();
            $('#key').val(insert_string);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use jquery, but i can help. If you don't need to process your input data but only validade for user, you can use the prop **pattern** in your HTML tag.

```
<input 
  type="text" 
  pattern="\w*_\w{1,}"
  title="Try the pattern test_test"/>
```

In this case, when you click on Button submit, the page will prenvent this action and show in this input the message passed on the prop **title**.

Hope help you, see ya!